# Why aren't my HTTP resources being cached?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, caching, asp.net-mvc-5, http-caching

I have several bundles configured for my MVC5 website.  Client-side caching is working for my images, but all of the bundles are being downloaded on every page load.

[image: Uncached bundle requests]

The query strings on the bundles do not change, and the content of the bundles is not being changed. (As far as I know, anyway -- I'm just reloading the page.)

[image: Bundle response headers]

The cache-related headers look like they *should* be caching these bundles, yet I'm downloading them every time.  What am I missing?

Comment: one possibility : Have you set <compilation debug="true" /> in web.config?

Comment: Not in production builds, which is where I'm running the traces shown above.  (Otherwise I don't believe the bundles would be "bundled," which they are.)

Comment: Observe value of Last-Modified header value for couple of reloads. Is it changing every time you refresh it? In screenshot it looks like bundle got modified at same time when request was served.

Comment: Yes, it does change every time.  But why is the browser requesting the resource at all after the first request?

Comment: If its getting modified every time you refresh page that means bundle is getting generated every time which shouldn't be case and probably that's reason caching will not work.